# Display number of times clicked on divs, from the get-go

Tags: jquery, count, string-length

I'm using this code to count the amount of times the user has clicked on a div which has the current css status .selected:

```
$(this)
    .click(function() {
    $(this);
    var n = $( ".selected" ).length;
    $( ".catched" ).text(n);
})
```

Then I'm displaying it with:

```
<div data-id="1" class="p001 mix">Div 1</div>
<div data-id="2" class="p002 mix">Div 2</div>

<div id="footer">
    <span class="catched"></span> / 151
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8hgna3fh/)

When the user hasn't clicked any div yet, it doesn't show the amount, but when the user clicked (anywhere) it displays the amount. I'd like to display it before the user clicks. Also when the user refreshed the page it needs to be displayed, since it remembers how many divs have the class selected with localstorage.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raise a `click()` event on the element immediately on load to populate the value:

```
$(this).click(function() {
    var n = $(".selected").length;
    $(".catched").text(n);
}).click(); // < add this
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8hgna3fh/2/)

Note that this code should be within your document.ready handler (as I amended it to be in the fiddle) and also your lone `$(this)` statement is redundant and can be removed.